# How to execute a command on a server? php queue laravel ssh

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, server, putty

I have a website in the Internet and I need to run command php artisan queue:listen on its server. I installed putty, logged in and tried to execute it, but it says php command not found :C. How should I do it proper way and how long this comand will run?

Comment: you may need to supply the path to php depending on how the server is set up

Comment: path to php, not your file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're positioned on the root of your proyect and run the command.

There´s also the option of running artisan commands programmatically:

```
Artisan::call('queue:listen');
```